# SQL query a range of records that fall within a Min and Max value

Tags: sql

For my Realty site I would also like to return the properties that fall within the user's requested price range from two drop down lists `MinPrice` and `MaxPrice` (which are also the field values).

Below is my statement thus far. It is working properly aside from the above requirement.

```
SELECT busname, email, render_pic, 
       area,logo, url, email, map, 
       description, tag, catch_phrase, region
FROM   Results
WHERE  STYLE LIKE 'varStyle' 
   AND REGION LIKE 'varRegion' 
   AND BEDROOMS LIKE 'varBedrooms' 
   AND BATHROOMS LIKE 'varBathrooms'
ORDER BY ID desc
```

Thank you SO MUCH in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
and Price between @minprice and @maxprice
```

Edit: To cover what @paxdiablo is suggesting, although I have no idea why a house would have anything besides a price...

```
and (minprice between @minprice and @maxprice 
or maxprice between @minprice and @maxprice
or @minprice between minprice and maxprice)
```

Comment: Not sure this is right, @Coov. OP seems to be looking for two overlapping ranges rather than a single data point being within a range. As in a house has a minimum and maximum cost and you're searching for houses that you can pay a minimum/maximum amount of money for.

Comment: @paxdiablo - I think you may be right, if you took "(which are also the field values)" to mean column values in the table.

Comment: the reason a house has a min/max price is because the realtor only gives indicative pricing, not a fixed price. That's standard practice since a house retailing for between 1 and 2 million will be seen by the buyer as 1m but by the seller as 2m, then it's up to the realtor to bring them together.

Answer (score 0):

Having two ranges that overlap (in the input and record) is a little ticky but you should try:

```
SELECT
    busname, ...
FROM Results
WHERE STYLE LIKE &varStyle
  AND REGION LIKE &varRegion
  AND BEDROOMS LIKE &varBedrooms
  AND BATHROOMS LIKE &varBathrooms
  AND (
         MINPRICE between &MinPrice and &MaxPrice
      OR MAXPRICE between &MinPrice and &MaxPrice
      OR (MINPRICE <= &MinPrice AND MAXPRICE >= &MaxPrice)
  )
ORDER BY ID desc
```

This will match if any price within your row min/max range is within your search min/max range (including when row min/max is entirely within search range) or if the entire search range is within your row range, which is what I think you were after.

In addition, you may want to rethink using `LIKE` unless those `var...` variable are actually allowed to have wild-cards. Some less intelligent DBMS' may not convert them into a more efficient `=` operation automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT busname, email, render_pic, 
       area,logo, url, email, map, 
       description, tag, catch_phrase, region
FROM   Results
WHERE  STYLE LIKE 'varStyle' 
   AND REGION LIKE 'varRegion' 
   AND BEDROOMS LIKE 'varBedrooms' 
   AND BATHROOMS LIKE 'varBathrooms'
   AND Price between varMinPrice and varMaxPrice
ORDER BY ID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would perform this type of query:

Only pass in values that are chosen by the user anything else that they don't specify leave as they are defaulted to NULL in the sproc below. I guessed at the parameter types but you get the idea. Also have added '%' so that the Region and Style are wild-carded.

The below query will return matching results based on none, any or all combinations of parameters supplied.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetProperties] 
      @style     VARCHAR(50)  = NULL
     ,@region    VARCHAR(50)  = NULL
     ,@bedrooms  TINYINT      = NULL
     ,@bathrooms TINYINT      = NULL
     ,@minPrice  INT          = NULL
     ,@maxPrice  INT          = NULL    
AS
BEGIN

     SELECT busname, email, render_pic, 
        area,logo, url, email, map, 
        description, tag, catch_phrase, region
     FROM   Results
         WHERE    (@style IS NULL OR STYLE LIKE '%' + @style + '%')
              AND (@region IS NULL OR REGION LIKE '%' + @region + '%')
              AND (@bedrooms IS NULL OR BEDROOMS >= @bedrooms)
              AND (@bathrooms IS NULL OR BATHROOMS >= @bathrooms)
              AND (@minPrice IS NULL OR MINPRICE >= @minPrice)
              AND (@maxPrice IS NULL OR MAXPRICE <= @maxPrice)
     ORDER BY ID desc

END
```