# Simple SQL question - pulling value between min and max

Tags: mysql

Okay, this is probably really simple but for some reason I'm totally fried on this and need some advice.

I have two columns in my database, budget_min and budget_max.

Oh the front end, I'm trying to build a search that will find everything between two budgets, say 1000 - 2000, or 2000 - 4000.

Need something like `where budget_min > 1000 && budget_max < 2000` but that obviously is not the correct query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query a range of records that fall within a Min and Max value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197250/sql-query-a-range-of-records-that-fall-within-a-min-and-max-value)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of direct options

```
where (X>22 AND X<55)
```

also

```
where X between 22 and 55
```